# Is possible to save locally a view object in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to save locally (on a file) a StackLayout object, because I need to save the current state of a page, so I was just wondering if could be possible.

**EDIT: Solution**

As I have seen, there is no solution!
This is because Views are not serializable, so it's neither possible to serialize the Views as a string (trust me, I have tried them all), the only way is to re-generate your page by saving and loading data of simple types such as int or string (because only simple data can be serialized).

Comment: you can't just save a View element.  You would need to write some custom code that would allow you to save and then regenerate the page state based on your model and whatever other parameters drive the page

Answer (score 0):

According to your needs, I think you only need to save the user's data and restore it at startup.

You can use File Handling in Xamarin.Forms to save the user's data, and then rewrite the OnAppearing method every time it starts, and restore the data inside the method.

For more information about File Handling, please refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=macos#saving-and-loading-files

Comment: Thanks for the responce, the problem is that i dont know how to save the user data, because the views and child objects are not serializable.

Comment: You can use a class or collection to store. Then serialize it to a string, and then use the document store I provided.

Comment: Ok, so you suggest me to store all the views in something like a list, than convert and save the list as a string?

Comment: 1. Serialize the list to a string. 2 Save with File Handling.